# jQuery plugin - return a css property if no options are filled

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I don't understand why if I'm trying to return css border property it returns me an empty string, even if I've set the border with css. I've also tried to set the border style using inline method, but still not working.. Any idea? Thank you!

```
(function($){

    var methods = {
    init : function( options, callbacks) {
        if(options === undefined) {
            return this.css("border");
        }

        return this.each(function(){
            if(options === null) {
                $(this).css("border","none");
                return;
            } else if(typeof options === "string") {
                $(this).css("border", options);
                return;
            } else if(typeof options === "object") {

                if(typeof options.style !== "undefined") {
                    $(this).css("border-style", options.style);
                } else {
                    $(this).css("border-style", "solid");
                }

                if(typeof options.width !== "undefined") {
                    $(this).css("border-width", options.width); 
                }

                if(typeof options.color !== "undefined") {
                    $(this).css("border-color", options.color); 
                }

                if(typeof options.radius !== "undefined") {
                    $(this).css("border-radius", options.radius);   
                }
            }
        });
    }
};

$.fn.border = function(method) {
    if ( methods[method] ) {
        return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else {
        return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    }
};

})(jQuery);
```

If I'm trying to return the color of the element.. everything seems to be ok.. but not with the border property.

Comment: Seems to work for me in the latest Google Chrome, though I set it up in a jsfiddle as a function, but it should work for you regardless. [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/BR95Y/).

Comment: Thank you DJDavid.. I've used another approach in resolving this.. I will put it as an answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this problem like this:

```
(function($){

    var methods = {
        init : function( options, callbacks) {

            return this.each(function(){
                        if(options === null) {
                    $(this).css("border","none");
                } else if(typeof options === "string") {
                    $(this).css("border", options);
                } else if(typeof options === "object") {

                                if(typeof options.style !== "undefined") {
                                    $(this).css("border-style", options.style);
                                } else {
                                    $(this).css("border-style", "solid");
                                }

                    if(typeof options.width !== "undefined") {
                        $(this).css("border-width", options.width); 
                    }

                    if(typeof options.color !== "undefined") {
                        $(this).css("border-color", options.color); 
                    }

                    if(typeof options.radius !== "undefined") {
                        $(this).css("border-radius", options.radius);   
                    }
                }
            });
        },
            getBorderStyle: function(options, callback) {

                    var elements = new Array();

                    this.each(function(){

                        var borderProperties = {};

                        borderProperties.style = this.style.borderStyle;
                        borderProperties.color = this.style.borderColor;
                        borderProperties.width = this.style.borderWidth;
                        borderProperties.radius = this.style.borderRadius;
                        borderProperties.element = this;
                        elements.push(borderProperties);
                    });

                    return elements;
            }
    };

    $.fn.border = function(method) {
            if ( methods[method] ) {
                return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
            } else if(method === undefined) {
                return methods["getBorderStyle"].apply(this, arguments);
            } else {
                return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
            }
    };

})(jQuery);
```